# Filter elements with xpath and select one as a first (two conditions)

Tags: xml, xpath

What is the best way to filter elements with specific values of one attribute and then put one of them as first according to value of another attribute.

```
<users>
<user id="1">
    <accounts>
        <account type="100" number="100456400100"/>
        <account type="110" number="100456400110"/>
        <account type="120" selected="1" number="100456400120"/>
        <account type="130" number="100456400130"/>
        <account type="140" number="100456400140"/>
        <account type="150" number="100456400150"/>
    </accounts>
</user>
<user id="2">
    <accounts>
        <account type="100" number="200456400100"/>
        <account type="110" number="200456400110"/>
        <account type="120" number="200456400120"/>
        <account type="130" number="200456400130"/>
        <account type="140" number="200456400140"/>
        <account type="150" selected="1" number="200456400150"/>
    </accounts>
</user>
```

I want to extend this xpath

```
users/user/accounts/account[@type='100' or @type='120' or @type='130' or @type='150']
```

to select only accounts with type 100, 120, 130 or 150. (In reality there are quite a lot account types so this is more effective than `!=100 and !=140`.... ). And to put the account with attribute `selected='1'` as first one.

Is there a way to do that with one xpath?

Answer (score 0):

Xpath does not provide `sort` functionality, so you'll need to use some post processing to do that (for example xslt).

In your example though, to correctly get what you want you'll need to use this Xpath

```
//users/user/accounts//account[@type='100' or @type='120' or @type='130' or @type='150']
```

Otherwise if you keep only one `/` before `account` you'll get the first account node only.